# conversion of boost::shared_ptr in boost::python function call

Tags: c++, python, boost, shared-ptr, boost-python

Consider the following example:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class A {};

class B : public A{};

void foo(boost::shared_ptr<A>& aptr) { }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mypy)
{
  using namespace boost::python;   
  class_<A, boost::shared_ptr<A> >("A", init<>());
  class_<B, boost::shared_ptr<B>, bases<A> >("B", init<>());
  def("foo", foo);
}
```

if I call the python code

```
import mypy
b = mypy.B()
mypy.foo(b)
```

I get

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    mypy.foo(B)
did not match C++ signature:
    foo(boost::shared_ptr<A> {lvalue})
```

I have googled around quite alot, but I can't find a good explanation / fix / workaround for this. Any help is quite welcome!

Comment: What happens if you have `foo` take a `boost::python::object` argument, and then extract the `shared_ptr` from that?

Comment: Sure, that would work, but I was hoping there would be a way without writing any additional wrappers for foo (there are quite a lot of those that I would need )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're asking for a non-const reference to a `shared_ptr<A>`, and your `b` instance in Python simply doesn't contain one; it contains a `shared_ptr<B>`.  While  `shared_ptr<B>` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<A>`, `shared_ptr<B>&` **cannot** be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<A>&`.

If you can modify `foo` to take a `shared_ptr<A>`, or `shared_ptr<A> const &`, that will solve your problem.

If not, you'll need to also wrap a version that accepts `shared_ptr<B>&`.